# Why am I getting good accuracy but low ROC AUC for multiple models?

Tags: r, model, logistic-regression, auc

My dataset size is 42542 x 14 and I am trying to build different models like logistic regression, KNN, RF, Decision trees and compare the accuracies.

I get a high accuracy but low ROC AUC for every model.

The data has about 85% samples with target variable = 1 and 15% with target variable 0. I tried taking samples in order to handle this imbalance, but it still gives the same results.

**Coeffs for glm are as follow:**

```
glm(formula = loan_status ~ ., family = "binomial", data = lc_train)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.7617   0.3131   0.4664   0.6129   1.6734  

Coefficients:
                                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                        -8.264e+00  8.338e-01  -9.911  < 2e-16 ***
annual_inc                          5.518e-01  3.748e-02  14.721  < 2e-16 ***
home_own                            4.938e-02  3.740e-02   1.320 0.186780    
inq_last_6mths1                    -2.094e-01  4.241e-02  -4.938 7.88e-07 ***
inq_last_6mths2-5                  -3.805e-01  4.187e-02  -9.087  < 2e-16 ***
inq_last_6mths6-10                 -9.993e-01  1.065e-01  -9.380  < 2e-16 ***
inq_last_6mths11-15                -1.448e+00  3.510e-01  -4.126 3.68e-05 ***
inq_last_6mths16-20                -2.323e+00  7.946e-01  -2.924 0.003457 ** 
inq_last_6mths21-25                -1.399e+01  1.970e+02  -0.071 0.943394    
inq_last_6mths26-30                 1.039e+01  1.384e+02   0.075 0.940161    
inq_last_6mths31-35                -1.973e+00  1.230e+00  -1.604 0.108767    
loan_amnt                          -1.838e-05  3.242e-06  -5.669 1.43e-08 ***
purposecredit_card                  3.286e-02  1.130e-01   0.291 0.771169    
purposedebt_consolidation          -1.406e-01  1.032e-01  -1.362 0.173108    
purposeeducational                 -3.591e-01  1.819e-01  -1.974 0.048350 *  
purposehome_improvement            -2.106e-01  1.189e-01  -1.771 0.076577 .  
purposehouse                       -3.327e-01  1.917e-01  -1.735 0.082718 .  
purposemajor_purchase              -7.310e-03  1.288e-01  -0.057 0.954732    
purposemedical                     -4.955e-01  1.530e-01  -3.238 0.001203 ** 
purposemoving                      -4.352e-01  1.636e-01  -2.661 0.007800 ** 
purposeother                       -3.858e-01  1.105e-01  -3.493 0.000478 ***
purposerenewable_energy            -8.150e-01  3.036e-01  -2.685 0.007263 ** 
purposesmall_business              -9.715e-01  1.186e-01  -8.191 2.60e-16 ***
purposevacation                    -4.169e-01  2.012e-01  -2.072 0.038294 *  
purposewedding                      3.909e-02  1.557e-01   0.251 0.801751    
open_acc                           -1.408e-04  4.147e-03  -0.034 0.972923    
gradeB                             -4.377e-01  6.991e-02  -6.261 3.83e-10 ***
gradeC                             -5.858e-01  8.340e-02  -7.024 2.15e-12 ***
gradeD                             -7.636e-01  9.558e-02  -7.990 1.35e-15 ***
gradeE                             -7.832e-01  1.115e-01  -7.026 2.13e-12 ***
gradeF                             -9.730e-01  1.325e-01  -7.341 2.11e-13 ***
gradeG                             -1.031e+00  1.632e-01  -6.318 2.65e-10 ***
verification_statusSource Verified  6.340e-02  4.435e-02   1.429 0.152898    
verification_statusVerified         6.864e-02  4.400e-02   1.560 0.118739    
dti                                -4.683e-03  2.791e-03  -1.678 0.093373 .  
fico_range_low                      6.705e-03  9.292e-04   7.216 5.34e-13 ***
term                                5.773e-01  4.499e-02  12.833  < 2e-16 ***
emp_length2-4 years                 6.341e-02  4.911e-02   1.291 0.196664    
emp_length5-9 years                -3.136e-02  5.135e-02  -0.611 0.541355    
emp_length10+ years                -2.538e-01  5.185e-02  -4.895 9.82e-07 ***
delinq_2yrs2+                       5.919e-02  9.701e-02   0.610 0.541754    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 25339  on 29779  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 23265  on 29739  degrees of freedom
AIC: 23347

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 10
```

**The confusion matrix for LR is as below:**

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction     0     1
         0    32    40
         1  1902 10788

               Accuracy : 0.8478         
                 95% CI : (0.8415, 0.854)
    No Information Rate : 0.8485         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.5842         

                  Kappa : 0.0213         

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16         

            Sensitivity : 0.016546       
            Specificity : 0.996306       
         Pos Pred Value : 0.444444       
         Neg Pred Value : 0.850118       
             Prevalence : 0.151544       
         Detection Rate : 0.002507       
   Detection Prevalence : 0.005642       
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.506426       

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

Is there any way I can improve the AUC?

Comment: This seems to be a question about data modeling and not a specific programming question. Such questions belong on a site like [stats.se] or [datascience.se], not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi sneha I suggest that you plot something like this https://tidymodels.github.io/probably/articles/where-to-use.html so that you can understand that it is easy to get 100% accuracy, what is hard is keeping a balance

Comment: Why do you think that 0.85 is good/high accuracy, if same value you can obtain without using any ML, just predicting 1 for all instances?

Comment: In other words, it seems like `loan_status ~ 1` would be about as good a model, as your complicated one.

Comment: It's imbalanced, and your model is trying to predict everything as 1, because in the confusion matrix, (1902+10788)/(10788+40+32+1902) = 0.99 of your predictions are 1, which is even more than what you see in the data; 2. the kappa value is too low, meaning it's not even better than randomly assigning your labels

Comment: My suggestion is to train the model using kappa, and you have to either weigh your 0s more than your ones, and sample more from the 0s than from the ones to make a balanced dataset. It's a bit tricky, but can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If someone presents a confusion matrix and talks about low ROC AUC, it usually means that he/she has converted predictions/probabilities into 0 and 1, while ROC AUC formula does not require that - it works on raw probabilities, what gives much better results. If the aim is to obtain the best AUC value, it is good to set it as an evaluation metric while training, which enables to obtain better results than with other metrics.